# Camunda 8 - SaaS vs self managed

Tags: installation, deployment, cloud, camunda, bpmn

We are trying evaluate the hosting options for Camunda 8 and understand that SaaS is completely run and managed by Camunda team which is great ,however for self managed option please could you advise -

1. What are the options/ways to host a self managed Camunda 8 ?
2. What all components are required for each of the options in point 1 above and any indicative cost for the components involved ?
3. What expertise is required to effectively run and managed self managed camunda 8 ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend

- reading this https://docs.camunda.io/docs/next/self-managed/about-self-managed/
- watching https://academy.camunda.com/c8-platform-overview and/or https://academy.camunda.com/c8-technical-overview
- and/or schedule a call with a Camunda presales consultant to discuss you requirements: https://camunda.com/contact/

Answer (score 0):

There are 5 major services [**Zeebe, Operate, Tasklist, Optimize and Identity**] which form the Camunda 8 platform.

Following are ways to deploy Camunda 8 as per [official docs](https://docs.camunda.io/docs/self-managed/platform-deployment/overview/):

- [Kubernetes](https://docs.camunda.io/docs/self-managed/platform-deployment/helm-kubernetes/overview/) [for production env]
- [Docker/Docker Compose](https://docs.camunda.io/docs/self-managed/platform-deployment/docker/) [for trying out locally of low traffic env]
- [Manual](https://docs.camunda.io/docs/self-managed/platform-deployment/manual/) - Only explore if you have manpower, resources for this.

Other than this, you will need Modeler

- Destop Modeler: if you have self managed Camunda setup
- Web Modeler: Readily available when using managed service. This comes with the benefit that [out-of-the-box Connectors](https://docs.camunda.io/docs/components/connectors/out-of-the-box-connectors/available-connectors-overview/) [Slack, Kafka etc] are already available to use.